# strange suspicious activity in router, should I be concerned?

Tags: router, security, internet, malware, modem

For a month now I've had dsl troubles, disconnection (pppoe lcd down) message every 5 minutes or hour.

Right now seeing my modem router logs I found eleven consecutive UDP PACKET entries, with various sources and destination(me) address. It says [PORT SCAN] on all of them.

What could this be? I'm the only one using router at the time and all I was doing is browsing reddit. The router lists 3 attached devices but I'm the only one actively using the internet.

Comment: As the term said, some random people are doing port scan of the whole internet... could be malicious in intent, or just surveying. As long as your router is secure and no one can login remotely - you will be fine. If you are worried someone may have access to your router, change your router password, and do what you need to secure it. It could be as simple as turning on the router firewall, and not allowing any incoming connection (especially if you know you are not hosting anything internal that you need to access from outside)

Comment: What if my devices are infected?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. These are typically just reports of someone else attempting to port scan you, i.e. trying to find open ports for potential attacks. Your router detected that and denied further attempts, which was logged for your information.

Comment: The router didn't make mention of it blocking them. Are my devices infected?

Comment: @Altoban No, why would they even block further attempts or log such information? Your disconnects might be the result of faulty hardware or some temporary problem at your ISP, but it's very unlikely caused by port scans alone.

Comment: I keep getting the port scan never saw them before.

Comment: @Altoban Don't worry too much about it as long as the IPs are external and not from LAN you should be fine.